# What type of lilac is this?

Tags: lilac

I live in zone 3 in Wyoming. It is a bold purple. The fragrance is amazing. The plant is about 10-12' tall and about 8-10' wide. I am moving and want to take it with me.

Comment: You could possibly take it with you in about a year of preparation.  Otherwise, you will kill it.  Whatever it is.  Lilac, dark purple?  You can move then purchase a new lilac or whatever for that home.  To dig this large of a mature plant and transplant without preparation that would take a good year... will kill it.

Comment: should there be a photo with this? can you add one please?

Comment: Does it have suckers (small stems coming from the ground near the main branches)? If so, you may be able to move a sucker or group of suckers. I've done it with French and common lilacs. Post a photo, please.

Comment: It will not let me post a picture. It does have suckers, but they are right beside the main, no way to separate.